# dereferencing pointer to incomplete type tcphdr->members

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I use socket to capture tcp data but build failed .
my environment is visual studio 2017.
I get error out put:

```
 1>/root/projects/frame_capture/framecapture.c:199:60:error : dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
 1>  int header_size = sizeof(struct ethhdr) + iphdrlen + (tcph->doff) * 4;
```

additional ,visual studio 2017 command line is:

```
"gcc" -W"switch" -W"no-deprecated-declarations" -W"empty-body" -W"conversion" -W"return-type" -W"parentheses" -W"no-pointer-sign" -W"no-format" -W"uninitialized" -W"unreachable-code" -W"unused-function" -W"unused-value" -W"unused-variable" -std=c++14 -x c -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -g2 -gdwarf-2 "g++" -O0 "3600000" -fthreadsafe-statics -W"switch" -W"no-deprecated-declarations" -W"empty-body" -W"conversion" -W"return-type" -W"parentheses" -W"no-format" -W"uninitialized" -W"unreachable-code" -W"unused-function" -W"unused-value" -W"unused-variable" -frtti -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=c11 -fexceptions -o "D:\linuxCproject\frame_capture\frame_capture\obj\x64\Debug\%(filename).o"
```

I build it with gcc in linux all  success.
linux code :

```
[root@localhost netinet]# gcc -o o.out framecapture.c
```

I want  to know how to fix this problem in visual studio.
the code line :

```
unsigned short iphdrlen;

struct iphdr *iph = (struct iphdr *)(Buffer + sizeof(struct ethhdr));
iphdrlen = iph->ihl * 4;

struct tcphdr *tcph = (struct tcphdr*)(Buffer + iphdrlen + sizeof(struct ethhdr));

int header_size = sizeof(struct ethhdr) + iphdrlen + (tcph->doff) * 4;
```

however I include the .h file like this :

```
#include<netinet/tcp.h>   //Provides declarations for tcp header
```

The definition in tcp.h is this :

```
    # else /* !__FAVOR_BSD */
struct tcphdr
  {
    u_int16_t source;
    u_int16_t dest;
    u_int32_t seq;
    u_int32_t ack_seq;
#  if __BYTE_ORDER == __LITTLE_ENDIAN
    u_int16_t res1:4;
    u_int16_t doff:4;
    u_int16_t fin:1;
    u_int16_t syn:1;
    u_int16_t rst:1;
    u_int16_t psh:1;
    u_int16_t ack:1;
    u_int16_t urg:1;
    u_int16_t res2:2;
#  elif __BYTE_ORDER == __BIG_ENDIAN
    u_int16_t doff:4;
    u_int16_t res1:4;
    u_int16_t res2:2;
    u_int16_t urg:1;
    u_int16_t ack:1;
    u_int16_t psh:1;
    u_int16_t rst:1;
    u_int16_t syn:1;
    u_int16_t fin:1;
#  else
#   error "Adjust your <bits/endian.h> defines"
#  endif
    u_int16_t window;
    u_int16_t check;
    u_int16_t urg_ptr;
};
# endif /* __FAVOR_BSD */
```

Comment: What is `struct tcphdr`?

Comment: The pointer dereference in the line with the error is for `struct tcphdr` (in `tcph->doff` specifically). Where is the definition for that struct?

Comment: @davmac I'm so sorry .now I have changed this struct tcphdr ..,thank you.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons thank you

Comment: @lydy looks like that definition is dependent on a preprocessor condition (`!__FAVOR_BSD`). I'm guessing that condition isn't being met, but I have no idea of how to adjust that.

Comment: @davmac , I adjust it by defining a new struct _tcphdr .

Answer (score 0):

finally,I solved this problem by my explore.

the main problem is build command.

project -> peoperties -> C/C++ -> Language -> C Language standard chosse correct standard such as C99/C89 or other,I chosse the Default which solved compile problem. set  c++ language standar same as C ,I chosse default, too.

after that I get command line :

```
"gcc" -W"switch" -W"no-deprecated-declarations" -W"empty-body" -W"conversion" -W"return-type" -W"parentheses" -W"no-pointer-sign" -W"no-format" -W"uninitialized" -W"unreachable-code" -W"unused-function" -W"unused-value" -W"unused-variable" -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -g2 -gdwarf-2 "g++" -O0 "3600000" -fthreadsafe-statics -W"switch" -W"no-deprecated-declarations" -W"empty-body" -W"conversion" -W"return-type" -W"parentheses" -W"no-format" -W"uninitialized" -W"unreachable-code" -W"unused-function" -W"unused-value" -W"unused-variable" -frtti -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fexceptions -o "D:\linuxCproject\icmprequest\icmprequest\obj\x64\Debug\%(filename).o"
```

tips: different standard are different while  dealing with `!__FAVOR_BSD` .